# Inconsistency in ability to access data member of loaded JSON object

Tags: python, django, simplejson

I'm loading a JSON string in Django using `simplejson`, thus:

```
obj = json.loads('{"name": "joe"}')
person = obj.name
```

This throws an error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

but when I pass `obj` down to the view template and print it out via `{{ obj.name }}`, it works! Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how the Django aspect of it works, but the object you get from `json.loads` is a Python `dict` object. That means it doesn't have attributes of its keys, but you can access them like you would any other dictionary:

```
obj = json.loads('{"name": "joe"}')
person = obj['name']
```

Comment: thank you. that was the problem. I have to figure out why things chance once passed through to view template.

Comment: @givp: That's because django's template languages allows "dict.key" syntax to access dictionary items

Comment: From this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

"Use a dot (.) to access attributes of a variable.

Behind the scenes

Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

Dictionary lookup
Attribute lookup
Method call
List-index lookup

Answer (score 4):

`json.loads` loads json into a python dictionary. So you must access it like a dictionary, i.e. `data['key']`.

Now, on the django template side of things, check the official [django templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) documentation.

Directly quoting:

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup

So basically, django templates allow you to access dictionary items using `data.key` syntax.